# Different view on Editing a Report

Tags: apex, reporting, administration, dashboard, configuration

When a user is trying to customize a Report, he is having a different view than a usual one.

[image]

Is this due to some permission issue or any settings mismatch. Coz even the Switch to Lightning and App menu is visible in a different manner.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not upgraded to Report Builder, *and* this user has Accessibility Mode enabled. You should go in to Setup > (Quick Find) > Reports and Dashboards Settings, and upgrade to the Report Builder. Please see [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_reports_and_dashboards_reportbuilder_upgrade.htm&type=5). Also, the other differences in the UI are because of Accessibility Mode. The user can to go their Personal Setup screen and disable the [Accessibility Mode](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessibility_enabling.htm&type=5) checkbox to get the standard UI.